# iOS application crashed due to "CFNetwork"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

The app is approved by Apple but it keep on crashing when downloaded from the App Store, The app works fine in Simulator.

Here's the crashlog.
From my searches it was indicated that it's due to Parse and but even after updating Parse and re submitting to Apple Review the app still crashes

```
    Incident Identifier: 1EA2D752-986F-45F0-B00D-258BBDAFFDBE
    CrashReporter Key:   16f85ba0a0b881573e6146c9e7ff8890a75db660
    Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
    Process:             Roadster [429]
    Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5BF8E8BA-B069-40C7-9345-5FB298584CFF/Roadster.app/Roadster
    Identifier:          App.Roadster
    Version:             4 (4.5)
    Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]

    Date/Time:           2016-06-24 02:16:02.02 +0530
    Launch Time:         2016-06-24 02:15:47.47 +0530
    OS Version:          iOS 9.3.2 (13F69)
    Report Version:      105

    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
    Triggered by Thread:  0

    Filtered syslog:
    None found

    Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
    0.224703     CFNetwork                  0x0000000184525990 TCP Conn 0x154f8b920 starting SSL negotiation
    0.225145     CFNetwork                  0x00000001845c7f18 TCP Conn 0x154f8b920 complete. fd: 19, err: 0
    0.226301     CFNetwork                  0x00000001845c9444 TCP Conn 0x154f8b920 event 1. err: 0
    0.849718     CFNetwork                  0x00000001845c951c TCP Conn 0x154f8b920 started
    11.240709    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184525a80 TCP Conn 0x154db8b00 SSL Handshake DONE
    12.478336    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184525990 TCP Conn 0x154db8b00 starting SSL negotiation
    12.479360    CFNetwork                  0x00000001845c7f18 TCP Conn 0x154db8b00 complete. fd: 15, err: 0
    12.479584    CFNetwork                  0x00000001845c9444 TCP Conn 0x154db8b00 event 1. err: 0
    12.865094    CFNetwork                  0x00000001845c951c TCP Conn 0x154db8b00 started
    12.889732    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184525a80 TCP Conn 0x154d799c0 SSL Handshake DONE
    13.189451    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184525a80 TCP Conn 0x154e87ad0 SSL Handshake DONE
    13.377730    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184525a80 TCP Conn 0x154d5cae0 SSL Handshake DONE
    13.667209    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184525a80 TCP Conn 0x154d3a890 SSL Handshake DONE
    13.726884    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184525990 TCP Conn 0x154d799c0 starting SSL negotiation
    13.731394    CFNetwork                  0x00000001845c7f18 TCP Conn 0x154d799c0 complete. fd: 13, err: 0
    13.735323    CFNetwork                  0x00000001845c9444 TCP Conn 0x154d799c0 event 1. err: 0
    13.895899    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184525990 TCP Conn 0x154e87ad0 starting SSL negotiation
    13.896511    CFNetwork                  0x00000001845c7f18 TCP Conn 0x154e87ad0 complete. fd: 7, err: 0
    13.898156    CFNetwork                  0x00000001845c9444 TCP Conn 0x154e87ad0 event 1. err: 0
    13.991708    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184525990 TCP Conn 0x154d3a890 starting SSL negotiation
    13.992223    CFNetwork                  0x00000001845c7f18 TCP Conn 0x154d3a890 complete. fd: 12, err: 0
    13.993698    CFNetwork                  0x00000001845c9444 TCP Conn 0x154d3a890 event 1. err: 0
    14.076219    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184525990 TCP Conn 0x154d5cae0 starting SSL negotiation
    14.076820    CFNetwork                  0x00000001845c7f18 TCP Conn 0x154d5cae0 complete. fd: 6, err: 0
    14.078054    CFNetwork                  0x00000001845c9444 TCP Conn 0x154d5cae0 event 1. err: 0
    14.227695    CFNetwork                  0x00000001845c951c TCP Conn 0x154d799c0 started
    14.229171    CFNetwork                  0x00000001845c951c TCP Conn 0x154d3a890 started
    14.518114    CFNetwork                  0x00000001845c951c TCP Conn 0x154e87ad0 started
    14.519612    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184623e5c Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
    14.519612    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184623e28 Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
    14.519612    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184675e50 Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton
    14.529775    CFNetwork                  0x00000001845c951c TCP Conn 0x154d5cae0 started
```

Comment: Does it crash on your device running connected to your Mac?

Comment: @Eiko No, It runs perfectly fine
Only crashes when downloaded from App Store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself :
Problem was due to Parse, Update Parse framework and it should solve the problem

Comment: What is the Parse framework? I am having similar symptom with an Airwatch MDM controlled App in my client's enterprise store.